# How to change this to ajax function?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to  use this ajax function instead of  load method.

currently in use

```
<div  id="post_<?php echo $post_id;?>">

<script type="text/javascript" >

$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#post_<?=$post_id?>').load('post.php?id=<?=$post_id?>')

 });
</script> 

</div>
```

I  need to change it with ajax function something like this

```
<script>
function ajax(){

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.onreadystatechange = function(){

if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){

document.querySelector('????').innerHTML =req.responseText;
} // how can i select the  div id
}
req.open('GET','post.php?id=<?=$post_id?>',true); 
req.send();

}
setInterval(function(){ajax()},1000);
</script>
```

But I am not sure how to select the div id . 
I need it for  refreshing without noticing(.load reloads the whole div) .

Comment: Could you add an argument to the ajax function that contains the post id? This way you could use it in the selector as you do in your original code. Is there any way to determine the post id? Otherwise, could you add a class to the div? I'm assuming there will be several of these div tags - thus the dynamic id...

Comment: are you using `jQuery`?

Comment: no i am not using jquery

Comment: @LadyLancer does the below code work?

Comment: working for only one div .... but   .load  works for all the div

Comment: how many divs do you have?

Comment: 5 in every page

Comment: please provide the code for the divs

Comment: it is the same code. divs appears like this  .... <div id=post_1> , <div id=post_2>  .....   this is all

Comment: it will only work for one div with the matching id, if the value of `$post_id = 12` it will work for `post_12`.

Comment: yes but with ajax function it's only working with post_1 ..... post_2 , post_3 is not showing anything . but .load works fine for all

Comment: is this inside a loop?

Comment: okay Mlax Wong's  solution worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :)

```
...
document.getElementById('post_<?php echo $post_id;?>').innerHTML =req.responseText;
...
```

Edit make script inside php loop

```
<?php foreach ($post_ids as $post_id): //I not sure how is your loop look like, this just example loop ^^"?>

    <div  id="post_<?php echo $post_id;?>">

    <script>
    function ajax<?php echo $post_id;?>(){

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    req.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){

    document.querySelector('#post_<?php echo $post_id;?>').innerHTML =req.responseText;
    } // how can i select the  div id
    }
    req.open('GET','post.php?id=<?=$post_id?>',true); 
    req.send();

    }
    setInterval(function(){ajax<?php echo $post_id;?>()},1000);
    </script>

<?php endforeach; //end of loop example?>
```

or this is another solution:

```
<?php foreach ($post_ids as $post_id): //this is your example loop i not sure how if your loop?>

    <div  id="post_<?php echo $post_id;?>" class="post" data-id="<?php echo $post_id;?>"></div>

<?php endforeach; //end of loop example?>

<script>
function ajax()
{
    var posts = document.getElementsByClassName('post');

    for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; ++i) 
    {
        var post = posts[i];  
        var post_id = post.dataset.id;

        req.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200)
            {
                post.innerHTML = req.responseText;
            }
        }

        req.open('GET','post.php?id=' + post_id,true); 
        req.send();
    }
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

}
setInterval(function(){ajax()},1000);
</script>
```

I saw that your javascript loop and request data every second, if the script inside the PHP loop normally will generate each post. That mean if your shown 5 post per page the loop will run 5 time. So the code above will prevent this problem.

Sorry for my English again .

Comment: @Lady Lancer Did your javascript ajax function inside PHP loop? I think not the selector problem. If the ajax function outside PHP loop the last post_<?php echo $post_id;?> will only get the last $post_id

Comment: yes this is what happened  ..... please tell what to do .. only last div is working

Comment: how do i put it in php loop

Comment: <?php foreach ($post_ids as $post_id): ?>
    
    <div  id="post_<?php echo $post_id;?>">
    
    <script>
    function ajax(){
    
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    req.onreadystatechange = function(){
    
    if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){
    
    document.querySelector('????').innerHTML =req.responseText;
    } // how can i select the  div id
    }
    req.open('GET','post.php?id=<?=$post_id?>',true); 
    req.send();
    
    }
    setInterval(function(){ajax()},1000);
    </script>
    
<?php endforeach; ?>

Comment: opps sorry I rewrite on my answer make it look nicer

Comment: and sorry for my english ^^"

Comment: This will create too many script tags and many function with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your php interpreter

```
document.querySelector('#post_<?php echo $post_id;?>').innerHTML =req.responseText;
```

Comment: okay it's working in only one div ...rest are not showing anything .....  i have multiple  divs in  same page .load was working inside every div. any solution

Comment: If you have more than 1 `<div>`, can you update your html code to show us what you want to affect?

Comment: it appears like <div id=post_1> , <div id=post_2> .... when using .load , it works fine ........ i just want to do the same with this kind of ajax function. seems like it  is only working with one div.  what i need to change here or should i use some other method ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `getElementById()`

```
<div  id="post_<?php echo $post_id;?>">
<script>
        function ajax() {
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('post_<?php echo $post_id;?>').innerHTML = req.responseText;
                } // how can i select the  div id
            }
            req.open('GET', 'post.php?id=<?=$post_id?>', true);
            req.send();
        }
    setInterval(function () {
        ajax()
    }, 1000);
</script>
```